# Jquery live replced to on not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-plugins, cordova

In my phonegap application intitally i used .live after knowing that that one deprecated so i switched to .on function.

using Live:

```
$("#addEditForm").live("submit", function(e) {
    var data = {
        firstname: $("#mFirstname").val(),
        lastname: $("#mLastname").val(),
        gender: $("#mGender").val(),
        dob: $("#dob").val(),
        email: $("#mEmail").val(),
        password: $("#mPassword").val(),
        conformPassword: $("#mConformPassword").val(),
        id:$("#mId").val()
    };
    alert(data.firstname);
    e.preventDefault();
```

When using ON:

```
$("#addEditForm").on("submit",function(e) {
alert("hi");
    var data = {
        firstname: $("#mFirstname").val(),
        lastname: $("#mLastname").val(),
        gender: $("#mGender").val(),
        dob: $("#dob").val(),
        email: $("#mEmail").val(),
        password: $("#mPassword").val(),
        conformPassword: $("#mConformPassword").val(),
        id: $("#mId").val()
    };
    alert(data.firstname);
    saveDatas(data, "#editPage", function() {
        $.mobile.changePage("index.html", {
            reverse: true
        });
    });
    e.preventDefault();

function saveDatas(details, cb) {
alert(details.firstname);
alert(details.firstname);
if (details.firstname == "") details.firstname = "[No Title]";
**dbShell.transaction(function(tx) {**
    if (details.id == "") {
        tx.executeSql("insert into nameDetail(firstname,lastname,gender,dob,email,password,conformPassword,date) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)", [details.firstname, details.lastname, details.gender, details.dob, details.email, details.password, details.conformPassword, new Date()]);
    } else {
        tx.executeSql("update nameDetail set firstname=?, lastname=?,gender=?,dob=?,email=?,password=?,conformPassword=?,date=? where id=?", [details.firstname, details.lastname, details.gender, details.dob, details.email, details.password, details.conformPassword, new Date(), details.id]);
    }
}, dbErrHandler, cb);
```

}

it shows exception like `E/Web Console(23700): Uncaught Error: TYPE_MISMATCH_ERR: DOM Exception 17 at file:///android_asset/www/js/index.js:51` that ** line..

here

```
addEditForm is my form id
```

my problem is `when using the live` the alert will work and give my name, `when using on` the alert is not display also tries pageshow,pageload nothing success .

[For on function i refer this doc](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Need some help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

As elements are added dynamically you can not bind events directly to them .So you have to use [Event Delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/).

```
$(document).on("submit","#addEditForm",function(e) { ..code here.. })
```

---

```
$(document).on("click","#editFormSubmitButton",function(e) { ..code here.. })
```

Syntax

```
$( elements ).on( events, selector, data, handler );
```

Comment: @Arut Good. When you are using `#editFormSubmitButton` event should be `click`  not `submit` .

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$(document).on("submit", "#editFormSubmitButton", function(e) {
    alert('Val');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use `.live()` the event is binded to the document object.

```
$(document).on("submit",'#addEditForm', function(e) {
})
```

Answer (score 1):

In the "on submit" function there is change in form id, is it the cause of your problem

Answer (score 0):

What is wrong with .live()

Use of the .live() method is no longer recommended since later versions of jQuery offer better methods that do not have its drawbacks. In particular, the following issues arise with the use of .live():

jQuery attempts to retrieve the elements specified by the selector before calling the .live() method, which may be time-consuming on large documents.
Chaining methods is not supported. For example, $(“a”).find(“.offsite, .external”).live( … ); is not valid and does not work as expected.
Since all .live() events are attached at the document element, events take the longest and slowest possible path before they are handled.
Calling event.stopPropagation() in the event handler is ineffective in stopping event handlers attached lower in the document; the event has already propagated to document.
The .live() method interacts with other event methods in ways that can be surprising, e.g., $(document).unbind(“click”) removes all click handlers attached by any call to .live()!
Whats the main differences between .live() and .on() functions?

Functionality: Instead of bubbling up the body and document level it is directly registered against the document.

Usage:
If we look at the 3 main event attachment methods we can see that they are very similar. Noticably the .live() doesn’t have a selector parameter.

$(selector).live(events, data, handler);                // jQuery 1.3+
$(document).delegate(selector, events, data, handler);  // jQuery 1.4.3+
$(document).on(events, selector, data, handler);        // jQuery 1.7+
Performance: I was going to create a jsPerf test but found someone already did the hard work! Here are the results of the performance of .live() and .on(). As you can see, .on() outperforms it’s predecessor .live(), it’s almost 3 or 4 times as fast!

Comment: thank you for your reply when using jquery mobile in the dropdown values are not able to set so my lead suggest to change latest versions...

Comment: If you are using phonegap then you can join phonegap developer chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11300/phonegap-framework